# Why is it subtracting incorrectly from char?

Tags: java, math, char, int

So here is my code:

```
public class charTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String bigNum = ("789");
    char s1 = bigNum.charAt(0);
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s1-1);
  }
}
```

It prints 7 on the first line, then it prints out 54 on the next line, why? I have a really really long number that I have as a string and I am referencing individual numbers in it seperately. I just did the subtraction test to see if it was working correctly. Any insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unicode point value of `7` (character) is `55`. Subtracting `1` gives `54`

The first `println` statement uses uses an `char` argument whereas the second uses an `int` (Subtraction of a `int` from a `char` causes [widening](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to an `int`)

to get `6` you could do

```
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(s1) - 1);
```

Comment: Not ASCII. `charAt` returns a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit.

Answer (score 0):

s1 is a char and prints as such.
s1 - 1 is being implicitly cast to an int as prints as an int. i.e. the toString method is being called on the value of 54.